# masked input inside xeditable text box not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable, maskedinput

I have an x-editable input for  my bootstrap application , which I'm using to edit usernames.
now i need to use the jquery.maskedinput.min.js to get the masked format while iam entering in text box which is appering when i click on the span as in the x-editable .this is my sample html code

```
<div id="sZip" class="profile-info-value ">
<span class="editable" id="Dob">dob</span>
</div>
```

and i achived the x editable by applying the j query like this

```
  $('#zip').editable({
                    type: 'text',
                    name: 'zip',
                    tpl:'   <input type="text" id ="zipiddemo" class="form-control    input-sm dd" style="padding-right: 24px;">'

                });
```

and it is working fine now i need to make that text box maskable ,but  when i am calling the  masked input function like this

```
$(".dd").mask("99999-?9999");
```

it is not working ,i dont know the exact reason.any help will be appreciated

Comment: please add a demo on jsfiddle.net and post the link here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not working because the x editable elements are added dynamically.

I hope this works.

```
$('#users a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    tpl: '<input type="text" id ="zipiddemo" class="mask form-control    input-sm dd" style="padding-right: 24px;">'
});

$(document).on("focus", ".mask", function () {
    $(this).mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/5050/)

Comment: hai  Dhiraj Bodicherla  i have one more doubt,how to show the password field in   x-editable .if i have the password  field from data base and i put the  type: 'password', in  editable function,when i click on the span then it will be shown as password and  after i click on submit button it is shown as '[hidden]'.my question is for first time when data coming from database ,when i put the value in span ,it just shown the actual value,how can i make that look like '[hidden]'

Comment: This worked for me. My only concern: how do we ensure that the data is populated in the template view? I made this change in two places. One prepopulates the form, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Or just do:

```
  $('#zip .editable').editable({
                type: 'text',
                name: 'zip',
                tpl:'   <input type="text" id ="zipiddemo" class="form-control    input-sm dd" style="padding-right: 24px;">'

            }).on('shown',function(){
$("input#zipiddemo").mask("99-999");
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9010/)

Answer (score 1):

Improving Dhiraj's answer, a more elegant way of doing such a thing would be using the `inputclass` attribute given by the Bootstrap X-editable API.

```
<a data-inputclass="mask"></a> <!-- input -->

$(document).on("focus", ".mask", function () {
    $(this).mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `.dd` input dynamically so below will not work

```
$(".dd").mask("99999-?9999");
```

Use `document` to find element and then mask it

```
   $(document).find(".dd").mask("99999-?9999");
```